# An unhandled exception of type 'System.Data.OleDb.OleDbException' occurred in System.Data.dll c#

Tags: c#, database, winforms, ms-access, datagridview

i already created the windows forms that the function is to add the information to the database. But, i have a problem. When i type the number like this one "SM0001" in the "Product Code" column, and hit enter, it store the data to the database and when i type the same number like i typed before, it does not prevent the user like the entered "Product Code" already exists in the database. So, this is my currently database (displayed in the datagridview in the system):

[image]

As you can see the row "1" and row "2" has the same "Product Code".. My question is: How do i prevent the user to entering the same number twice?

i already change the Primary Key in the database to the "Product Code", but here is the error that i am getting:

The error is:

```
An unhandled exception of type 'System.Data.OleDb.OleDbException' occurred in System.Data.dll

Additional information: The changes you requested to the table were not successful because they would create duplicate values in the index, primary key, or relationship. Change the data in the field or fields that contain duplicate data, remove the index, or redefine the index to permit duplicate entries and try again.
```

The error is on:

`cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();`

on this function:

```
private void AddDatabase(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            using (OleDbConnection conn = new OleDbConnection(connectionString))
            {
                string query = "INSERT INTO [Table] ([ProductCode], [Description], [Price]) VALUES (@ProductCode, @Description, @Price)";
                conn.Open();
                using (OleDbCommand cmd = new OleDbCommand(query, conn))
                {
                    cmd.Parameters.Add("@ProductCode", System.Data.OleDb.OleDbType.VarChar);
                    cmd.Parameters["@ProductCode"].Value = this.numericTextBox1.Text;
                    cmd.Parameters.Add("@Description", System.Data.OleDb.OleDbType.VarChar);
                    cmd.Parameters["@Description"].Value = this.textBox3.Text;
                    cmd.Parameters.Add("@Price", System.Data.OleDb.OleDbType.Integer);
                    cmd.Parameters["@Price"].Value = this.textBox4.Text;
                    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery(); // The error is here
                    if (_choice.comboBox1.Text == "English")
                    {
                        System.Media.SoundPlayer _sound = new System.Media.SoundPlayer(@"C:\Windows\Media\Windows Exclamation.wav");
                        _sound.Play();
                        DialogResult _dialogResult = MessageBox.Show("Added Successfully!", "Success", MessageBoxButtons.OK);
                        if (_dialogResult == DialogResult.OK)
                        {
                            ViewDatabase(sender, e);
                            ClearTextBoxes(sender, e);
                        }
                    }
                }
                conn.Close();
            }
        }
```

I wanted to when user type the same "Product Code", the messagebox will appear that the typed "Product Code" is not allowed because it is exists on the database and not give an error (terminate the program from running).

How do i fix it?

Thank you

Your answer will be great appreciated!

Comment: I suppose u use a dataset/list as datasource?

Comment: There are many ways you can go to solve your problem, but the immediate answer to your question is the try/catch/finally block. Then you can work on database code, a local `DataTable` with keys/constraints, etc.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error you're getting is quite normal. You can't insert duplicates into the primary key (nor can they contain 'NULL') column. More info about primary keys:

[W3schools - primary key](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_primarykey.asp)

[database.about.com](http://databases.about.com/cs/administration/g/primarykey.htm)

Before executing `AddDatabase` you should be checking whether the key is already present in the database. you can do this in many different ways.

1. Execute a select on the database

   ```
   SELECT TOP 1 ProductCode FROM Table WHERE ProductCode = 'this.numericTextBox1.Text'"
   ```

   If this query produces a result, then the productcode is already present in the database and the query should **Not** be executed
2. Check the datasource of your datagridview

   As datasource for your datagridview, you're probably supplying a List/Dataset. You can check your list for the existance of your newly entered ProductCode. You could use link here or just iterate the source. (whatever floats your boat)

   If you can give me the type of datasource then i might supply a code example
3. Check your Datagridview

   If your datagridview contains all the records of the database then you can iterate the the rows and check if the first column contains an productcode equal to the newly entered product code.

   something among the lines of

   ```
    foreach (DataGridViewRow row in dgvDataGridView.Rows)
         {
         if(row.Cells[0].Value.toString().equals(this.numericTextBox1.Text))

              { 

              // Productcode is already present
              // Throw message/exception Or whatever
              break; 
              }
         }
   ```

I would opt for option 1, as you datagridview/datasource may not show/keep all records from `Table`

Comment: No Problem! Have fun :)

Answer (score 1):

Before executing `INSERT` you can check if database is already contains `ProductCode` (which seems to be a *key* in your table).

Something like (copy/paste code from one of my projects, but should be clear)

```
 var command = new OleDbCommand("SELECT COUNT(*) FROM results WHERE id = ?", _connection);
 command.Parameters.Add("id", OleDbType.Date).Value = id;
 if ((int)command.ExecuteScalar() == 0)
 {
     // not exists
 }
```

Suggestion: do not make `AddDatabase` an event handler, but create a separate class to handle database operations, make method `AddDatabase` there and call it from event handler.

You could have 2 methods then `Exists(id)` and `Add(...)`, so in the event you can do simple duplicate check:

```
if(Database.Exists(id))
{
    // show errror
    return;
}
DataBase.Add(...);
```

Answer (score 0):

If  your error is 
an unhandled exception of type 'system.data.oledb.oledbexception' occurred in system.data.dll additional information: Overflow
The cloumn in DB is little for note or digits 
Please change cloumn format to bigger 
Number ----> integer upper to double 
Tanks